# QuickBlox TSendPush error

Tags: ios, quickblox

My ios app is running into a problem using the QuickBlox sdk's TSendPush. -(void)completedWithResult:(Result*)result gets called but result.success is false.

The debug info from the call is:

```
parameters:{
    "event[environment]" = development;
    "event[event_type]" = "one_shot";
    "event[message]" = "payload=eyJhcHMiOnsic291bmQiOiJkZWZhdWx0IiwiYWxlcnQiOiJIZWxsbyBtYW4hIn19";
    "event[notification_type]" = push;
    "event[push_type]" = apns;
    "event[user][ids]" = 673543;
}

raw body:event[environment]=development&event[event_type]=one_shot&event[message]=payload%3DeyJhcHMiOnsic291bmQiOiJkZWZhdWx0IiwiYWxlcnQiOiJIZWxsbyBtYW4hIn19&event[notification_type]=push&event[push_type]=apns&event[user][ids]=673543
```

and I get "Forbidden. Need user." 673543 is a valid user (well, a user of that ID is listed in the QuickBlox admin panel)

Any ideas gratefully received

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that you have to login and do on user behalf in order to send push notifications

just do

```
 [QBUsers logInWithUserLogin:@"igorigor" password:@"igorigor"  delegate:self];
```

or

```
[QBUsers logInWithUserEmail:@"qbuserqqqq34r5@gmail.com" password:@"qbuserr345" delegate:self];
```

After this you can use **TSendPush** method

Comment: Yes. Thanks. Just worked this out, my login was failing sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The *sending* user wasn't logged in correctly (I had been using their Facebook username but for some reason Facebook wasn't sending it to me)